# Image URL is broken for custom attributes in custom tab

Tags: magento2.2

In **Magento 2.2.1**: I created a custom attribute (let's say "photo"), then I created a `photo.phtml` to call the attribute as below:

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php echo $product->getData('photo'); ?>
```

I then displayed it on the product page as a new tab. I uploaded some image in the backend. While I am able see the images in the "More information" tab (which is the default tab showing additional attributes) I am not able to see any image in the "Photo" tab. All the images have broken link like this: hxxp://mydomain.com/{{media url=
Can someone point me to the right direction? How to write my photo.phtml correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that indeed my photo.phtml is not correct, although it worked for Magento 1.8.1 it won't work for 2.2.1. I made a copy of the description.phtml and modified to:

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getPhoto(), 'photo') ?>
```

and that solved the problem: image URL are displayed correctly.